# javascript highcharts jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, get

I am having trouble charting a json file in highcharts javascript. Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My test.json file simply contains: `[1, 2]`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = $.get('test.json');
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
                },
            series: [{
                data: [a]
            }]
        });
    });  
</script></head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what error r you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you're not seeing anything (or a weird graph) it's cause you should have:

```
data: a
```

as opposed to

```
data: [a]
```

The data field is supposed to be an array of integers. As it stands now it looks like an array of array of integers which will be misinterpreted by Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the array as an element inside a array resulting a array of array of integers. this makes it plot only in some odd cases but not always

odd case means [[1,2,3,4]], this will not be plotted

for example
[[1,2], [2,4]] indicates 2 points to be plotted at (1,2) and (2,4) positions in the chart.

so in your case it plots only point at (1,2) instead of 2 points at you want,

[1,2] indicates 2 points with y value of first at 1 and second at 2

I think that is the issue you are getting, instead of 2 points only one point is plotted

so it should be

```
date: a
```

but not

```
data: [a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your AJAX call, according to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), you should use callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $.get('test.json', function(data) {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
            },
        series: [{
            data: data
        }]
      });
    });
  });  
</script>
```

So: create chart in callback, which is called after data from AJAX comes to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise your chart in the $.get() callback, because then you avoid missing data.

```
    $(function () {
        var a = $.get('test.json',function(data){
          $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
                },
            series: [{
                data: data
            }]
          });
        });
    });
```